# Problems with a footer in a grouped uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, footer, margins

I have a grouped UITableView with some sections (with an header title). I want to add a footer to the first section, so I use

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return @"some lines of text...........bla bla bla bla bla etc etc");
        break;
    default:
        return nil;
        break;
    }
}
```

I have one problem:

1. the distance between the footer end and the title of the next section is quite big. I don't know why.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change the footer height programmatically or using interface builder.

Comment: Changing it in IB doesn't change anything, so I use -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section and I return the footer heigth for portrait and landscape mode, but how can I access the footer height of the first section in (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration?

Comment: I used -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section checking the orientation and in (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration I reload the table.